# Why does Terser Webpack plugin generate different file names in development and production modes?

Tags: webpack-5, terser

I have recently upgraded to Webpack 5, and had to drop Uglify in favour of the [Terser plugin](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/terser-webpack-plugin/).

However now when I build my project I get different output files when I'm in different modes.

```
// mode: 'development'

vendors-node_modules_axios_index_js-node_modules_vue-loader_lib_runtime_componentNormalizer_j-66b5c5.js
vendors-node_modules_css-loader_dist_runtime_api_js-node_modules_css-loader_dist_runtime_cssW-d8fbbe.js
vendors-node_modules_fullstack-phone_client_index_js-node_modules_fullstack-phone_server_load-a7472a.js
vendors-node_modules_vuedraggable_dist_vuedraggable_umd_js.js
```

```
// mode: 'production'

284.js
328.js
730.js
```

This is making it hard to link the files in my templates and load them into my project without writing some logic in the templates to specifically pick the chunks I need, find out the file names and load them.

How can I have Terser output the same file names in both development and production modes, but keep the right chunking?

Answer (score 1):

if use webpack5, change chunkIds to 'named'in production mode; see doc:  https://webpack.js.org/configuration/optimization/#optimizationchunkids

```
optimization: {
  chunkIds: 'named'
},
```